# JQuery Tree File Expand Folders

Tags: jquery, plugins, directory, expand, filetree

regarding this SO question: ["jquery file tree - folder open by default?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098843/jquery-file-tree-folder-open-by-default)

i tried to get the workdaround of Bermo running...

It works but only for folders like

```
/images/fruit/
```

but not for a folder like:

```
/images/fruit/cherry/
```

This is my function call:

```
 function fileTree(f,a){
                $('#uploadFileTreeViewFiles a').live('click',function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                $('#uploadFileTreeViewFiles').fileTree({ 
                    root: f,
                    script: 'dateiverwaltung/listDirectory',
                    multiFolder: false,
                    expandedFolders: [a]
```

f ist the rootfolder and a the folder to expand.

i have no idea how to get this working.