# jquery file tree - all folders open by default?

Tags: jquery

I have used the jquery file tree script (located at http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) and the php connector version and have a beautiful 2-column, expanding menu as a result.

The client now also wants an identical version of the page but with all the folders expanded by default on page load. I haven't a clue how to do this. I have seen a post explaining how to expand specific folders by default but I need to expand all by default as this is a recursive file tree that the client will add folders to and I don't and shouldn't want to have to update javascript every time they add a folder.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! My jQuery knowledge is basic. I'm just coming into jQuery from an ActionScript3 medium-complexity bkgnd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed something similar, but with a search functionality - search on file and folder name stored in a database.
To complicate my side further there was different levels of security. In the end it was just to complicated for jqueryFileTree.

However, playing around with Matija's response :
[jquery file tree - folder open by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098843/jquery-file-tree-folder-open-by-default)

```
if (o.expanded != null) {
    $(c).find('.directory.collapsed').each(function (i, f) {
         /*if ((o.expanded).match($(f).children().attr('rel'))) {*/
            showTree($(f), escape($(f).children().attr('rel').match(/.*\//)));
            $(f).removeClass('collapsed').addClass('expanded');
        //};
    });
}
```

I commented out the if statment and I managed to expand all. I also had to change

```
if(o.expanded == undefined) o.expanded = ''; 
if(o.expanded == undefined) o.expanded = null;
```

else it would trigger even if I did not want it to. I wanted to expand all just on search.

Majid unfortunately your code did not work for me. closedFolders.length was always 0

Answer (score 2):

It seems the plugin does not provide a config to do that. However you could try to open all folders *after the plugin has finished rendering the tree* by:

```
$(".directory a").click();
```

And that might prove a bit tricky as it also presents no `complete` callback.

**Update**

If the folders contain sub-folders, you need to open the new ones too. So you could use a function like this:

```
function openThem() {
  var closedFolders = $(".directory:not(.expanded) a");
  if(closedFolders.length > 0) {
    window.setTimeout(openThem, 1000);
    closedFolders.click();
  }
}
openThem();
```